# How to set the format of text in Korge?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, korge

The  [2048 Game tutorial](https://blog.korge.org/korge-tutorial-writing-2048-game-step-1/) shows

```kotlin
text("0", cellSize * 0.5, Colors.WHITE, font) {
    setTextBounds(Rectangle(0.0, 0.0, bgScore.width, cellSize - 24.0))
    format = format.copy(align = Html.Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER) // there is an error
    centerXOn(bgScore)
    alignTopToTopOf(bgScore, 12.0)
}
```

I use android studio 4.1 and Korge  plugin 1.12.2.2. The IDE shows: **Unresolved reference.**

I change this line to

```
setFormat(align = TextAlignment.MIDDLE_CENTER)
```

The error of IDE disappear, but the text don't show either.

How to fix it, and set the text in the middle of the object of **bgScore**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The korge in new version

```
text("0", cellSize * 0.5, Colors.WHITE, font) {
    setTextBounds(Rectangle(0.0, 0.0, bgScore.width, cellSize - 24.0))
    // format = format.copy(align = Html.Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER) // there is an error
    alignment = TextAlignment.MIDDLE_CENTER // it works in version korGE 2.0
centerXOn(bgScore)
    alignTopToTopOf(bgScore, 12.0)
}
```